# Numpy: adding n-dimensional vector to m-dimensional vector to get (n, m) matrix

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have the array [1,2,3,4,5].
I want to "add" the array [2,4,6,8] to it so I get

```
[[3,5,7,9],
 [4,6,8,10],
 [5,7,9,11],
 [6,8,10,12],
 [7,9,11,13]]
```

(or its transpose).

There is probably a function for this but I can't seem to find it because I'm not sure what to search for.

Comment: Search for `outer add`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Divakar, the best way is to use `add.outer`:

```
a1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a2 = np.array([2,4,6,8])

np.add.outer(a1,a2)
```

But you can also explicitely [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) your `a1` array to the proper shape, then add to `a2`:

```
a1[:,None]+a2
# essentially equivalent to:
# a1.reshape(-1,1)+a2
```

Both produce:

```
array([[ 3,  5,  7,  9],
       [ 4,  6,  8, 10],
       [ 5,  7,  9, 11],
       [ 6,  8, 10, 12],
       [ 7,  9, 11, 13]])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.